# Weird behavior on Netty Beta1

Tags: netty

Previously, we used Netty 4.0.0.Alpha7 to develop our Websocket application, and everything works fine. Once Netty 4.0.0.Beta1 has been released, we incorporate them to our application. However, no client can connect to the application. Initially, I thought it was our problem so we get websocket example from github and it doesn't work also.

The weird thing is our application and example can work fine when we run on our local machine but, once deployed to our server, it doesn't work. When we roll back to Netty Alpha7 on the same server, it works fine again. Does anybody experience this kind of problem?

Here is exception found when I ran the Websocket example in our server (Linux). This exception is not found when I ran on local machine (Windows7)

```
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: io.netty.buffer.IllegalBufferAccessException
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1019)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.freeHandlerBuffersAfterRemoval(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:962)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:904)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireInboundBufferUpdated(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:909)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:401)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:302)
    at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: io.netty.buffer.IllegalBufferAccessException
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:81)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter.freeInboundBuffer(ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter.java:46)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.freeHandlerBuffersAfterRemoval(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
    ... 10 more
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: io.netty.buffer.IllegalBufferAccessException
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1019)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.freeHandlerBuffersAfterRemoval(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:823)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.access$1300(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext$5.run(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:808)
    at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:259)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:305)
    at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: io.netty.buffer.IllegalBufferAccessException
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:81)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter.freeInboundBuffer(ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter.java:46)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.freeHandlerBuffersAfterRemoval(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
    ... 7 more
```

> Update, it seems this is a problem of java version. Originally, java version was 6u17 and the application doesn't work. After I update it to 6u38, the application works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I add exception detail in the content from running the example in our server. Unfortunately, we have rolled back to use Alpha7 so we are not able to replicate the problem right now, and we didn't save the exception yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess you try to access the buffer after you removed the ChannelHandler from the ChannelPipeline. This is not allowed since Beta1 to make sure we not leak any memory on removal. If you want to remove the ChannelHandler and forward the remaining stuff in the buffer to the next ChannelHandler in the ChannelPipeline use ChannelPipeline.removeAndForward(..) .

See also:
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1054#issuecomment-13760528

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your response. I am not sure this is the same case because I used the example at https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server. 
I try analyzing the differences between running on my local machine and server. As I run in the server by using shell script, I find out that if I set CLASSPATH variable in shell script, the example will throw exception as above. On the other hand, if I skip the scripting setting CLASSPATH variable and use -cp in java command, the example works fine. What do you think about this case?

Comment: Sounds strange... I can not think of any good reason why the CLASSPATH would affect this. Maybe you have some mixed versions in there ?

Comment: Sorry to give you misleading information. I finally found it might be a problem of java version I am using on the server. The server originally run on java 6u17, and the example doesn't work. Once I set system path to run java 6u38, it work fine. It might be java version issues. Thank you for your help.